# Alternating hockey stick sum $\sum_{m=k}^M (-1)^m \binom{m}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'd like to calculate the following sum efficiently

$$S(k, M) = \sum_{m=k}^M (-1)^m \binom{m}{k}$$

I've tried to use generating functions and write

$$
S(k,M) = \sum_{m=k}^M  [x^k] (-1-x)^m
= [x^k] \frac{(-1-x)^{k+1}-(-1-x)^{M+1}}{2+x}
$$

But because there's $2+x$ in the denominator, it will still be a sum and not just coefficient extraction from the numerator as happens in the usual hockey stick formula.

Another thing I tried is to write $\binom{m}{k} = \binom{m+1}{k+1} - \binom{m}{k+1} $, so we have

$$
S(k,M) = \sum_{m=k}^M  (-1)^m  \binom{m+1}{k+1} - \sum_{m=k}^M  (-1)^m \binom{m}{k+1}
= \dots
$$

Oh, and just noticed: up to sign these are [A108561](https://oeis.org/A108561). (The columns or something maybe some sort of diagonals.) There's the formula $T(n,k) = T(n-1,k) + T(n-2,k-1) + T(n-2,k-2)$ there. Could that be helpful, or do we end up generating the whole triangle? That would be too big, I have $M=10^7$. Although, I am calculating this for all $k=1,\dots, M$ so if we can calculate these numbers along as we go that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\eqalign{S(k,M) - S(k,M-1) &= (-1)^M {M \choose k} = (-1)^M \left({M-1 \choose k-1} + {M-1 \choose k}\right)\cr &= -S(k-1,M-1) + S(k-1,M-2) - S(k,M-1) + S(k,M-2))} $$
so
$$ S(k,M) = -S(k-1,M-1) + S(k-1,M-2) + S(k,M-2) $$
with $S(k,M) = 0$ if $k > M$ or $k = 0$ and $(-1)^M$ if $k=M$.

Note that to compute $S(k,M)$ for all $k = 1, \ldots, M$ you will need
$S(\ldots,M-1)$ and $S(\ldots, M-2)$.  So you don't need to keep the whole triangle in memory, just the last two $M$'s in addition to the one you're doing now.

Comment: I can't get the indexes to work: https://www.online-python.com/RntbuE5qvP

Comment: For $k=0$, the value should be $\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^{M}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

Since you have accepted an answer, I presume you have obtained the answer you wanted. Therefore, I will only post a concise alternative, in case you're interested to explore further.

**Combinatorial Argument**

Select a subset of $k+1$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,...,M+1\}$. Let $n_{o}$ be the number of subsets in which the largest element is odd and $n_{e}$ be the number of subsets in which the largest element is even. We have the following relation:

$$
S(k,M) = n_{o}-n_{e}
$$

Using this argument, we can obtain various recursive relations in the form of:

$$
S(k,M)=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\cdot S(k-j,M-n)
$$

where $n<\min(k,M)$. One example is the following relation, when $n=1$:

$$
S(k,M)=-S(k,M-1) -S(k-1,M-1)
$$

**Remarks**

By selecting $n>1$, it's possible to skip some values of $M$. However, you will not get the complete values of $k=1,...,M$. So I leave that choice to you.

Comment: That recursion being simpler is better. But I can't get these calculations correct. `sk1M1:  -2 -2
skM1:  -2 -2
skM:  4 4
skMPrev =  4
skM1 is the sum 4 + -4 
sk1M1:  -2 -2
skM1:  0 -1
skM:  2 3
skMPrev =  4
skM1 is the sum 2 + -1 `

Comment: I tried to code it like this (Python): https://www.online-python.com/z3Ig8oDnKX

Comment: @ploosu2 here's an implementation in Python https://www.online-python.com/I4UbASsGRr . I noticed the other answer has a wrong value for $k=0$

Comment: Thanks! I still had a bit of problem with that, since I have $M$ fixed and large. But I managed to massage your last equation to something I then used iteratively: $S(k,M) = \frac{1}{2}\left(-S(k-1,M)+(-1)^M \binom{M+1}{k} \right)$. I'll still keep the first answer as accepted altough I ended up using this more, since it basically solves the problem (albeit with more terms)). Thanks to both, these were really helpful.